# Echo placeholder if field is empty

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have an input that I'd like to put a placeholder text in, but *only if* it's respective value is an empty string. The value that should go in the textbox is echoed from a PHP array, but if this value is empty, the placeholder should be echoed instead. At the moment, I've got this code:

```
<?php echo sponsorData('address0') == '' ? 'Address Line 1' : 'Other'; ?>
```

`sponsorData()` just gets stuff from an array; it's only argument is the key. The important bit here is it returns astring.

This code gives odd behaviour; I get stuff like `Hello worldAddress Line 1`, where `Hello world` is the user typed text and `Address Line 1` is obviously the placeholder. Strangely, the placeholder gets stored into the array on submission.

My question is this: can someone offer a correction of my ternary operator or, if that won't work, tell me to do an inline `if` statement (blegh)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into operator precedence issues. Try:

```
<?php echo (sponsorData('address0') == '' ? 'Address Line 1' : 'Other'); ?>
```

(put brackets around the ternary operator statement).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It turns out I was echoing instead of returning the string from `sponsorData()`... JamWaffles is like "how do brains work?"

Answer (score 4):

try the following code:

```
<?php echo ((sponsorData('address0') == '') ? 'Address Line 1' : 'Other'); ?>
```

felix

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have this working ok, I don't think the error lies there. Here is how I would do it:

```
$address0 = sponsorData('address0');

$address0 = !empty($address0) ? $address0 : 'placeholder';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that the `sponsorData('address0')` may have spaces, so you can add the `trim` function, like this:

```
<?php echo ((trim(sponsorData('address0')) == '') ? 'Address Line 1' : 'Other'); ?>
```